# Netsh interface missing under Windows 8 embedded

Tags: networking, windows-8, netsh

I have a client that uses Windows 8 embedded as a platform for media player devices. One function of this software is to administrate the player's IP address. For this function netsh is used on the background.

On the Windows 8 development platform one can simply use

```
Netsh interface ipv4 ... etc etc
```

To configure network settings. On the Windows 8 embedded devices however, Netsh doesn't seem to have the 'interface' module available.

Does anyone know how to enable the interface context of Netsh?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does Netsh do *anything* when run on that machine?  What does `Netsh /?` tell you? What is the exact Netsh command you are trying to run?

Comment: Netsh works, using /? shows a few contexts that are installed, but quite a few less than doing it on a regular Win8 installation. This is what gives us the impression that there is simply something missing in the embedded version that we need to enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the "[Network Command Shell Interface Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa940055%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx)" component has been added to your Win8 Embedded image.

> This component is loaded by Netsh.exe and implements the interface context for it.

Comment: Thanks I'll pass this along to my client. Too bad the page doesn't specify HOW you're supposed to do this :(
Hopefully my client (who is the one that actually installs the Win8) knows how.

Comment: Is there a way to install this component on Win 8 Emb _after installation_ (i.e. on a running OS) and _offline_?

Comment: I have found `X:\Catalog\6.2\9200.16384\amd64\modules\FeaturePack\WinEmb-Remote-Access-Service~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.9200.16384.emd` file on Win 8 Emb Std ISO. Can anyone share with me, how can I install EMB file? Or is it installed via some CAB file in that folder? Which one?

Comment: I have found a way to install the EMD file ([src](https://connecttech.com/resource-center/kdb327-support-for-bluestorm-and-blue-heatpci-drivers-under-windows-embedded/)): `DISM /online /add-module /modulepath:absolute\or\relative\path\WinEmb-Remote-Access-Service~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.9200.16384.emd`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 Standard (== Embedded) you need to add the "Remote Access" component to get `netsh interface` to work.